# Access all batch outputs at the end of epoch in callback with pytorch lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

The documentation for the `on_train_epoch_end`, https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/callbacks.html#on-train-epoch-end, states:

> To access all batch outputs at the end of the epoch, either:
>
> 1. Implement training_epoch_end in the LightningModule and access outputs via the module OR
> 2. Cache data across train batch hooks inside the callback implementation to post-process in this hook.

I am trying to use the first alternative with the following LightningModule and Callback setup:

```py
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning import Callback

class LightningModule(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        self.automatic_optimization = False

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        return {'batch': batch}

    def training_epoch_end(self, training_step_outputs):
        # training_step_outputs has all my batches
        return

class MyCallback(Callback):
    def on_train_epoch_end(self, trainer, pl_module):
        # pl_module.batch ???
        return
```

How do I access the outputs via the `pl_module` in the callback? What is the recommended way of getting access to `training_step_outputs` in my callback?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I have the exact same problem.
Also what is "the module OR" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the outputs of each training batch in a state and access it at the end of the training epoch. Here is an example -

```py
from pytorch_lightning import Callback


class MyCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.state = []
        
    def on_train_batch_end(self, trainer, pl_module, outputs, batch, batch_idx, unused=0):
        self.state.append(outputs)
        
    def on_train_epoch_end(self, trainer, pl_module):
        # access output using state
        all_outputs = self.state
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, this does work. But I believe it has sub-optimal memory footprint for multiple callbacks? The outputs will need to be concatenated at some point which means that a new tensor will be created in each callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recipe to convert the epoch-end hook from an older version of Lightning to >= 2.0:

Before:

```py
import lightning as L

class LitModel(L.LightningModule):
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        ...
        return {"loss": loss, "banana": banana}
    
    # `outputs` is a list of all bananas returned in the epoch
    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
        avg_banana = torch.cat(out["banana"] for out in outputs).mean()
```

After:

```py
import lightning as L

class LitModel(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # 1. Create a list to hold the outputs of `*_step`
        self.bananas = []
    
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        ...
        # 2. Add the outputs to the list
        # You should be aware of the implications on memory usage
        self.bananas.append(banana)
        return loss
    
    # 3. Rename the hook to `on_*_epoch_end`
    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        # 4. Do something with all outputs
        avg_banana = torch.cat(self.bananas).mean()
        # Don't forget to clear the memory for the next epoch!
        self.bananas.clear()
```

The example here is using the training hook, but it applies to the respective validation, test and predict hooks as well.

Sources:

- [Lightning 2.0 release notes](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/releases/tag/2.0.0)
- [Lightning migration guide](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/upgrade/migration_guide.html)